# Casting a multidimensional array to Data object for TF inference

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow

I am currently using the Swift release of Tensorflow in my iOS app.
My model is working fine, but I am having trouble copying the data into the first Tensor so I can use the neural net to detect stuff.

I consulted [the testsuite inside the repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/swift/Tests/InterpreterTests.swift), and their code is working as follows:

They are using some extensions:

```
extension Array {
    /// Creates a new array from the bytes of the given unsafe data.
    ///
    /// - Note: Returns `nil` if `unsafeData.count` is not a multiple of
    ///     `MemoryLayout<Element>.stride`.
    /// - Parameter unsafeData: The data containing the bytes to turn into an array.
    init?(unsafeData: Data) {
        guard unsafeData.count % MemoryLayout<Element>.stride == 0 else { return nil }
        let elements = unsafeData.withUnsafeBytes {
            UnsafeBufferPointer<Element>(
                start: $0,
                count: unsafeData.count / MemoryLayout<Element>.stride
            )
        }
        self.init(elements)
    }
}

extension Data {
    /// Creates a new buffer by copying the buffer pointer of the given array.
    ///
    /// - Warning: The given array's element type `T` must be trivial in that it can be copied bit
    ///     for bit with no indirection or reference-counting operations; otherwise, reinterpreting
    ///     data from the resulting buffer has undefined behavior.
    /// - Parameter array: An array with elements of type `T`.
    init<T>(copyingBufferOf array: [T]) {
        self = array.withUnsafeBufferPointer(Data.init)
    }
}
```

to create the array containing the data, and a Data object from that:

```
static let inputData = Data(copyingBufferOf: [Float32(1.0), Float32(3.0)])
```

Afterwards, they copy the `inputData` into the neural net.

I've tried to modify their code to load an image into a [1,28,28,1] Tensor.
The image is looking something like this:

```
[[[[Float32(254.0)],
               [Float32(255.0)],
               [Float32(254.0)],
               [Float32(250.0)],
               [Float32(252.0)],
               [Float32(255.0)],
               [Float32(255.0)],
               [Float32(255.0)],
               [Float32(255.0)],
               [Float32(254.0)],
               [Float32(214.0)],
               [Float32(160.0)],
               [Float32(130.0)],
               [Float32(124.0)],
               [Float32(129.0)],
...
```

you get the point.

But if I try to cast that to Data / init Data with the image data I somehow only get 8 bytes:

```
private func createTestData()  -> Data {
        return Data(copyingBufferOf:
            [[[[Float32(254.0)],
               [Float32(255.0)],
               [Float32(254.0)],
...
```

[image: 8 bytes of data]

Same goes for the code in the tests, but for them, it is fine (2*Float32 = 8 bytes).
For me, that is considerably too small (should be 28*28*4 = 3136 bytes)!

1. Is there something I am missing (have I overlooked something)?
2. What do I need to do to get my images into the correct arrays/data types?

Comment: I have no experience with Tensorflow, but that `Data(copyingBufferOf:)` method expects a flat array  of Floats. For a nested array you may need to flatten it into a simple array first.

Comment: @MartinR you were absolutely correct. I am not a Swift developer, this is just a simple app to showcase something for university, so I had no idea how arrays and things work in TF Swift.
After I did a lot of digging and experimenting I came to the same conclusion. 

Half an hour later, I read your reply :D.
If you want to, you can post it as an answer (it is correct, after all) so you can get those sweet points. If you do not want to do that, I'll post an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Swift `Array` is a fixed-sized structure with (opaque) pointers to the actual element storage. The `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` method calls the given closure with a buffer pointer to that element storage. In the case of a `[Float]` array, that is a pointer to the memory address of the floating point values. That's why

```
array.withUnsafeBufferPointer(Data.init)
```

works to get a `Data` value representing the floating point numbers.

If you pass a nested array (e.g. of type `[[Float]]`) to the `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` method then the closure is called with a pointer to the `Array` structures of the inner arrays. So the element type now is not `Float` but `[Float]` – and not a “trivial type” in the sense of the warning

```
/// - Warning: The given array's element type `T` must be trivial in that it can be copied bit
///     for bit with no indirection or reference-counting operations; otherwise, reinterpreting
///     data from the resulting buffer has undefined behavior.
```

What you need to do is to flatten the nested array to a simple array, and then create a `Data` value from the simple array.